# Get temp-table's name in code

Tags: progress-4gl

I'm trying to get this temp-table's name/variablename ('TT_Test') in code so I could compare it:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE TT_Test NO-UNDO
    FIELD Test AS CHAR
.
```

I've tried to use this without success:

```
PROCEDURE testProc:
    DEF VAR name AS CHAR NO-UNDO.

    name = TT_Test:NAME.

END PROCEDURE.
```

Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cName = TEMP-TABLE tt_test:NAME.